# Render a controller in Twig - Unexpected "render" tag - expecting closing tag for the "block" tag defined

Tags: controller, twig, render, symfony

In Symfony2, at least until Symfony 2.4, it was possible to render controllers like this in twig

```
{% render(controller("MyBundle:Default:method", { 'call' : 'action' })) %}
```

With Symfony 3, this throws an Exception

```
Unexpected "render" tag (expecting closing tag for the "block" tag defined
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I lost some time to find out a solution, but it's simple, so I share it with you. Maybe it can spare someone's time

```
{{ render(controller("MyBundle:Default:method", { 'call' : 'action' })) }}
```

Simple, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

this case also arrives while using sonata bundle

error twig

```
     {% render url('sonata_admin_short_object_information', {
                    'code':     sonata_admin.field_description.associationadmin.code,
                    'objectId': sonata_admin.field_description.associationadmin.id(sonata_admin.value),
                    'uniqid':   sonata_admin.field_description.associationadmin.uniqid
                    }
                )%}
```

solution i tried:

```
 {{ render(url('route_name', {'param': value})) }}
```

working example

```
           {{render(url
                        ('sonata_admin_short_object_information', 
                    {
                    'code':     sonata_admin.field_description.associationadmin.code,
                    'objectId': sonata_admin.field_description.associationadmin.id(sonata_admin.value),
                    'uniqid':   sonata_admin.field_description.associationadmin.uniqid
                    }
                ))
            }}
```